# Firebase Auth - Doesnt login issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Basically my app has a AuthWrapper where it either goes loginPage or homePage.

```
class Wrapper extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final res = watch(authControllerProvider);

    if (res != null) {
      return HomePage();
    } else {
      return LoginPage();
    }
  }
}
```

On App start, it logins fine if logged in or goes loginpage if not, but for example:

- if not logged in, goes login page, and if user goes register screen and registers it doesnt login, basically after pushing to pages, the AuthWrapper doesnt work, is there a way to resolve this.

registerpage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hubx/screens/HomePage/homepage.dart';
import 'package:hubx/screens/authentication/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:hubx/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:hubx/shared/theme/theme_colors.dart';
import 'package:hubx/shared/widgets/loading_widget.dart';
import 'package:hubx/shared/widgets/theme_widgets.dart';
import 'package:hubx/shared/validator.dart';
import 'package:theme_provider/theme_provider.dart';

class RegisterPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _registerFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    final TextEditingController _displayNameController =
        TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

    final FocusNode _displayNameFocusNode = FocusNode();
    final FocusNode _emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
    final FocusNode _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _displayNameFocusNode.unfocus();
        _emailFocusNode.unfocus();
        _passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: SAppBar(context, 'Register'),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Scrollbar(
            child: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Card(
                      color:
                          (ThemeProvider.controllerOf(context).currentThemeId ==
                                  'dark')
                              ? MyThemesColor.darkBG
                              : MyThemesColor.lightBG,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16))),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _registerFormKey,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                children: [
                                  TextFormField(
                                    controller: _displayNameController,
                                    focusNode: _displayNameFocusNode,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    autovalidateMode:
                                        AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                    validator: (value) =>
                                        Validator.validateField(
                                            value: value!,
                                            fieldName: 'Display Name'),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Display Name',
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                                            Icons.format_color_text_outlined)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    controller: _emailController,
                                    focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    autovalidateMode:
                                        AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                    validator: (value) =>
                                        Validator.validateEmail(email: value!),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Email',
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 8),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    controller: _passwordController,
                                    focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                                    autovalidateMode:
                                        AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                    validator: (value) =>
                                        Validator.validatePassword(
                                      password: value!,
                                    ),
                                    obscureText: true,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Password',
                                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.password_outlined),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 32),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Consumer(
                                builder: (context, ref, child) {
                                  final authService = ref(authServiceProvider);
                                  if (!authService.isLoading) {
                                    return Container(
                                      width: double.maxFinite,
                                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                        onPressed: () async {
                                          _displayNameFocusNode.unfocus();
                                          _emailFocusNode.unfocus();
                                          _passwordFocusNode.unfocus();
                                          if (_registerFormKey.currentState!
                                              .validate()) {
                                            final authService = context
                                                .read(authServiceProvider);
                                            await authService
                                                .registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                                              _emailController.text,
                                              _passwordController.text,
                                              _displayNameController.text,
                                              '',
                                            )
                                                .then((value) {
                                              if (value != 'Success') {
                                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                  msg: value,
                                                );
                                              }
                                            });
                                          }
                                        },
                                        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.userEdit),
                                        label: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            'REGISTER',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return LoadingWidget(
                                      loadingSize: 30,
                                      loadingColor: MyThemesColor.theme,
                                      title: '',
                                    );
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    Consumer(
                      builder: (context, ref, child) {
                        final authService = ref(authServiceProvider);
                        if (!authService.isLoading) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context)
                                  .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                              ));
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Already have an account? ',
                                  style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 0.5),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Login',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                    color: MyThemesColor.theme,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return SizedBox.shrink();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

authControllerProvider:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:hubx/repositories/auth_repository.dart';

final authControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthController, User?>(
  (ref) => AuthController(ref.read)..appStarted(),
);

class AuthController extends StateNotifier<User?> {
  final Reader _read;

  StreamSubscription<User?>? _authStateChangesSubscription;

  AuthController(this._read) : super(null) {
    _authStateChangesSubscription?.cancel();
    _authStateChangesSubscription = _read(authRepositoryProvider)
        .authStateChanges
        .listen((user) => state = user);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _authStateChangesSubscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void appStarted() async {
    final user = _read(authRepositoryProvider).getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '######### SIGNED IN');
      print('######### SIGNED IN');
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '######### NOT SIGNED IN');
      print('######### NOT SIGNED IN');
    }
  }

  void signOut() async {
    await _read(authRepositoryProvider).signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Include the full code of the AuthWrapper.

Comment: And please rephrase the issue. What is the expected behaviour and what is the current buggy behaviour?

Comment: ive updated, the AuthWrapper above. 

Basically the auth wrapper either shows loginpage or homepage, ive also got a register page which user can navigate from the login page:
`Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterPage(),));`. The issue is once registered, the authWrapper isnt active and doesnt navigate to homepage, am i suppose to add the `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homepage(),));` after registering?

Comment: Okay. Post the code of the RegisterPage and that of the AuthControllerProvider.

Comment: Ive updated the main post containing code for registerpage and authcontrollerprovider

Comment: You should navigate to the Wrapper instead. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should navigate to the wrapper after registration. And then the provider will take care of where to navigate to based on authentication state.

```
final authService = context.read(authServiceProvider);
var value = await authService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
  _emailController.text,
  _passwordController.text,
  _displayNameController.text,
);
if (value != 'Success') {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: value,
  );
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Wrapper(),));
}
```